# Autorefresh file header using JAutodoc

Tags: java, android, eclipse, refresh, jautodoc

I'm using JAutodoc for the creation of JavaDoc comments and file headers in my Android project. Now I want to auto-refresh the file headers on after saving a file (the headers contains the last modification date and the name of the last editor, see below).

Is this even possible with this tool or could one recommend another tool / plugin for this task?

An example header (it normally contains a bunch of asterisks, but I can't get them displayed here..):

> Filename: awenkoQMErfassung.java
>
> Modification date: 01.10.2014
>
> @author: sven.kannenberg

Answer (score 0):

Since `JAutodoc 1.12.0` released 2015-01-04 it is possible to add/replace the file header on save.

Enable it with menu `Window => Preferences => Java => Editor => Save Actions =>` check `Additional actions` and press `Configure...` => Select tab `JAutodoc` and check `Add file header`